# JFrog REST API client app fails to build with missing org.apache.commons.* packages

Tags: artifactory, apache-commons

We have a Java app that was built using 2017 version of JFrog Java services jar. Today I am trying to rebuild it using the latest Jfrog libraries. I see that the new services jar doesn't have org.apache.* packages in it.

This is how I built the JFrog services jar.

1. Downloaded 2.8.6 source zip and expanded it
2. Upgraded gradle to latest and ran "gradle clean build -x test -x javadoc"
3. Then copied services/build/lib/*services-2.8.6.jar ONLY to my project lib folder

When I try to build, I see so many compilation errors. The old lib was called something like artifactory-java-client-ning-services-1.2.0-all.jar.

How do I build one like it?

I changed the build strategy to point to jcenter to download and create uber jar with all the dependencies with gradle file like below. I am still running into missing classes.

Below is one of those errors:

> error: package org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient does not exist
> import org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient.ProxyConfig;

In Netbeans IDE that I am using, I can expand each package in a jar and see the classes in it. I don't see anything under org.jfrog.artifactory.client package. That is strange.

My build.gradle:

```
group 'org.jftog.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.13

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.jfrog.artifactory.client:artifactory-java-client-services:+'
    implementation 'org.jfrog.artifactory.client:artifactory-java-client-api:+'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of compilation error you are getting? is it a compilation error or an issue with missing 3rd party dependencies (apache commons)?

Comment: It is missing Apache commons package. The old uber jar has everything in it. The latest version doesn't seem to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources of the Artifactory Java client can be found in the [jfrog/artifactory-client-java](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java) GitHub repository.
The [services](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/tree/master/services) module used to be built as an uber jar containing 3rd party dependencies. On Oct 2019 the build has [changed](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/commit/4d9eed5093032947ae05b807a1a46f6feec99001#diff-74048ce29e9b763ea6209f3e3ee168405f8eb8a8a3a95210359623abac03e46c) to create a thin jar instead of an uber jar.
To solve you issue you can either:

- Include the 3rd party dependencies of the service module when building you application
- Revert the change in build.gradle and continue to build an uber jar

Instead of building from source, you can consume the artifact from [jcenter](https://jcenter.bintray.com) where is it being published by JFrog. The artifacts are published together with [Maven .pom](https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jfrog/artifactory/client/artifactory-java-client-services/2.9.1/:artifactory-java-client-services-2.9.1.pom) files which contains all the required 3rd party dependencies (all of them are available in jcenter).
In addition, there is an example [Github project](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/artifactory-client-java-examples) which shows how to consume the client library using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Were they removed because JFrog doesn't have any dependencies on them now or you are expecting client apps to add those dependencies themselves?
In the 2nd case, JFrog classes will start throwing class not found exceptions. I don't expect this to be these case. If it is, it doesn't make sense why someone would NOT document these dependencies.

Comment: I added the jar dependencies and am able to go past those issues.
I see missing class compilation errors for org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient*.
How do I resolve that dependency?
Plus I have some code that has been using ch.qos.logback.classic from old jar. I don't see them either.

Comment: @videoguy I updated the answer with more details on how to find/consume the 3rd party dependencies

Comment: Thanks Dror! I am building this using Netbeans IDE with its Ant based project file system. Thats why I am looking for final jar to include in Netbeans as a lib dependency.

Comment: I used the example project instead of source code package. Modified the gradle build to create uber jar. That fixed apache package issues. But I still see missing Artifactory references.

error: package org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient does not exist
import org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient.ProxyConfig;

Comment: I updated my question to include more context above. Please check.

Comment: @videoguy not sure where this error is coming from. This class was deprecated around 2017

Comment: I figured that class changed its name and it is using Builder pattern now. Once I changed it, everything compiled. I am gradle newbee. How can you make it download all dependency jars to libs folder? When you deploy, how do you know which jars besides artifactory sdk to be included?

Comment: Gradle knows how resolve transitive dependencies, you can read about it here - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html . I suggest opening a new question for this

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution to an answer:</sub>

> I found that the artifactory sdk changed and I was using stale classes. I fixed those references in my classes to use newer SDK counterparts and the issues were gone.
>
> I ended up using following gradle file to build everything I needed:
>
> ```
> group 'artifactory-client-sdk'
> version ''
>
> apply plugin: 'java'
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8
> buildDir="${rootDir}/../out/artifactory_client_sdk"
> def signbridge_lib="${rootDir}/../libs"
> jar.baseName = 'artifactory-client-sdk'
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
>     testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
>     implementation 'org.jfrog.artifactory.client:artifactory-java-client->services:+'
>     implementation 'org.jfrog.artifactory.client:artifactory-java-client-api:+'
> }
>
> jar {
>    from {
>        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
>    }
>    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA','**/org/jfrog/example'
> }
>
> task copyJar(type: Copy) {
>     from jar // copies output of file produced from jar task
>     into "${signbridge_lib}"
> }
>
> build.finalizedBy copyJar
> ```